# How to elegantly replace certain characters in one string with characters in another at the same index?

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

I want to replace each instance of a character in one string with a character at the same index in another string. If no character exists at that index, leave it as it is.

Here's my solution with a list comprehension (Python 3):

```
string1 = "food is delicious"
string2 = "orange is not delicious"
string3 = "".join([string2[i] if i<len(string2) and c=="o" else c for i, c in enumerate(string1)])
print(string3)
```

Result

```
frad is delicidus
```

It feels like there should be a better way though, for example using str.replace somehow. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to iterate both the strings, till the longest of the them is exhausted. The smaller string will be filled with `fillvalue`

```
>>> s1 = "food is delicious"
>>> s2 = "orange is not delicious"

>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> "".join([c2 if (c1 == 'o' and c2) else c1 for c1, c2 in zip_longest(s1, s2, fillvalue='')])
'frad is delicidus'
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest solution i found:

```
a="food is delicious"
b="orange is not delicious"
''.join(y if x is 'o' else x for (x, y) in zip(a, b))
>>>> frad is delicidus
```

Note that the result string will have the length of the shorter of the two, because otherwise it would be undefined what to replace the remaining `o`s with.

Comment: **Don't** use `is` to compare objects.

Comment: Also, this will not work if the `a` is longer than `b`.